# Find a commercial transistor with known channel width, channel length, dielectric thickness, etc for experimental purposes?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, dimensions

I want to buy a commercial transistor, with known dimensions (channel width/length, dielectric thickness, materials etc.) This data is necessary to select a transistor most compatible with my experiments (radiation measurements.)

From the datasheets I have looked at ([like this example](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntb5860nl-d.pdf),)  I can find only the package dimension information.

---

Application specific context:

In my research I fabricate thin film transistors to detect ionizing radiation: - X-ray produce e-h pairs in the dielectric

- holes are trapped at dielectric/semiconductor interface
- the field produced from extra holes shifts Vth.

I am interested to see how a commercially available transistor performs vs our fabricated device.

The commercial transistor is optimized for the following:

- Low IGS.leakage (since we measure charge accumulated in the dielectric, this needs to stay trapped.)
- Stable Vth (we measure the shift in Vth caused by charge accumulated in the dielectric, so this value needs to be stable)
- Thick dielectric (the more dielectric the more it interacts with X-rays)
- Large W/L  increase area for X-ray to interact with

With W/L and dielectric thickness information, I can choose good candidates.

Comment: I would say this is a proprietary technology-related information, which the manufacturers would not disclose. It is also not a useful information for the vast majority of the target audience.

Comment: The literal answer is "inside the transistor in question".  Get your package-removing equipment warmed up, dust off your electron microscope, and find out -- and then expect that in a year or two it'll be different.  A data sheet promises what a part will *do* -- what's inside the part is subject to change, and somewhat proprietary to the manufacturer.  Asking for that information is getting close to "can I please have blueprints so I can clone your parts and sell them myself, for cheap?"

Comment: @EugeneSh yeah i thought so.. For my application the actual dimensions of the transistors are important, as I am thinking of using it as a radiation sensor (so senses depending on the area of the dielectric etc).

Comment: Well, it is not the *intended* use of the transistor

Comment: @TimWescott, yeah it makes sense it is proprietary, but i'm hoping there is some, maybe generic/outdated ones, that have info online without having to open them up. It's not so sell them, but more that I need that info to know if their part is suitable for my application, but I understand that in general they don't want to give it up as people could just copy it

Comment: @EugeneSh., yeah for sure! I'm getting creative..

Comment: @Leo your question is a bit o X Y problem. According to your comments, you have a problem X *"How to find a transistor with known channel width, channel length, dielectric thickness, etc for experimental purposes?"* but you ask Y *"How to find that data on arbitrary transistor?"*. Consider editing this question to reflect what you need directly.

Comment: @Mołot Do you think the refined question would be answerable?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I believe there will be a *better chance* for useful answer. As written, this question is perfectly answerable with "You can't" but it is not an useful answer for OP.

Comment: @Leo How many question did you ask, where, instead of asking what you want to know, "how can I build a radiation sensor", you ask something else, then people in your comments ask what you're asking for, then a lot of people spend time on it, in the end it all turns out your idea is infeasible, which adding the goal of all this would have allowed people to explain earlier? **Please stop asking new questions about building radiation sensors without directly asking about radiation sensing**. Radiation sensing is not a taboo – just mention it **in the question itself**! Stop wasting our time!

Comment: @Mołot Sometimes StackExchange is just one big XY problem.

Comment: @Mołot thanks, your wording is more clear. I updated the question

Comment: @MarcusMüller In this question I want to specifically find out if there are commercial transistors that give out it's specific W/L and dielectric thickness. The wording suggested from molot was perfect.  "how to build a radiation sensor?" would not specifically point to the information I am trying to find out

Comment: Every single time you ask something like that, it would have been useful to know what you're asking this for. I'm not telling you to not ask the question you care about, but to directly include the info that you're asking this because you want to build a radiation sensor out of it directly in the question. More info in the question on why you're asking *can't* hurt you – usually, it allows experienced folks to give hints based on your question on how to achieve your goal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I always try and limit the information to the most relevant for the question to be answered, I think this way it is most useful for future viewers who have the same doubt. But you're right in Electrical Engineering stack exchange I'm often asked for extra information so i'm clearly not exhaustive enough. I'll add more context in the future

Comment: That'd be great, thank you :)!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added context as an EDIT so it is below the specific question information

Comment: That is a *great* addition! It also gives answerers much more insight into the level of understanding you have :) At least for me, it gave me a moment of "ah, that Leo knows way more about semiconductor production than I do!"

Comment: @MarcusMüller i got there in the end :) "ah, that Leo knows way more about semiconductor production than I do!" - wouldn't count on it. From transistor fabrication - X-ray characterization - PCB design for integration with readout electronics - and app development for sensor readout with phone, this research projector has turned me into the jack of all traded and master of none...

Comment: Your edits change the meaning of the question entirely. That's very frustrating for anyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 4):

This is unlikely to be a workable approach for your radiation sensor. You should keep in mind that the manufacturer can change the manufacturing process significantly, without notifying customers, as long as the resulting transistors still meet their datasheet specifications.

If you are trying to measure the total ionizing dose of gamma or X rays then the nature of the gate oxide is extremely important. The manufacturer might make the oxide thinner, or change between wet and dry growth, and the transistor would still meet the datasheet but its radiation response would change dramatically.

A similar situation exists if you want to use bipolar transistors and see how they respond to neutrons, for example.

It is because of these issues that dedicated fab lines are used when the customer needs predictable and reliable behavior in a radiation environment.

Comment: Thanks, very clear why for commercial purposes you would need a dedicated fab line. 
I have EDITED the question adding some context. I am interested in comparing a commercial transistor under radiation, with what i fabricate, for a benchmark. So am looking for the best commercial candidate for a trial, not to start production, a transitor with:  thick dielectric, large W/L, low leakage and stable VTh

Answer (score 2):

There are few guarantees that the silicon process will not change over time.
However, you are likely to have more success using a memory IC rather than a single transistor or FET structure.
While IC manufacture can change over time, it's less likely, and certainly within a datecode/revision should be fairly consistent.
In days gone by, one of the [first digital cameras](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/using-dram-as-a-camera-sensor) was produced using a 1K ram chip.

Today, it might make more sense to use a camera chip as a radiation sensor. The layout and size of the chip is very consistent, and unlikely to vary over time for a given part. There's lots of work on this using cellphone cameras to read.

However, why are you not considering using a simple structure such as a [PIN diode](https://physicsopenlab.org/2016/03/08/pin-diode-radiation-detector/) as a detector? That would seem ideal as a single structure device.
Something like the [Vishay K857PE](https://www.vishay.com/docs/80136/k857pe.pdf) would seem ideally suited. Since it's an optical device you can easily see/measure areal characteristics, even if they don't tell you the channel depth.

Comment: Very interesting. I am trying to build a device that stores charge, and can be read at a later moment. The PIN diode unfortunately doesn't do this. I have seen (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2666032620300132 )a capacitor attached to a revese-bias diode, so to store the information. Am not sure what the advantages of the diode + capacitor vs just capacitor with a thick dielectric that interacts with X-ray and creates e-h pairs. My guess is that it is a lot easier to separate the e-h pairs in the diode, than in the capacitor dielectric, thus avoiding recombination.

Comment: @Leo, I can't see why a PIN diode and op-amp integrator would not provide the requirement.

Comment: my understanding is that a PIN diode detector would create a current (in reverse bias), and I would measure said current to extract radiation dose. So the device works only while a bias is applied. I would like to readout the sensor with an RFID, fully passive, so the sensor would have to "store" the information about radiation fully passive, and then be read out with an RFID at a later moment. For example I think Cap + Diode would work, as fully passive the Photo diode discharges the Capacitor, which i can read out at a later moment.

Comment: I think your diode could be a very good benchmark for sensitivity, if it works well i could add a battery to the design. I will buy it and test it. Maybe attaching it to a capacitor is the trick. Thanks Jack

Comment: @Leo This may interest you: https://physicsopenlab.org/2016/03/08/pin-diode-radiation-detector/ Doing accumulation by pulse counting with a small MCU may be viable for you. The MCU could also implement your RFID functionality.